# AMQP C++ implementation

Tags: c++, python, amqp

We are writing C++ code which needs messaging. Is there a free/open-source and stable AMQP server available that has equally stable C++ client library with it. We also need to provide Python interface of our code to users (idea is to do maximum stuff in C++ and expose the API in Python).

What can be best way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be so slow replying to this.  We just found it.  

There is interest in taking the RabbitMQ C client and providing an interface for it in C++ which follows C++ idioms. This has been discussed on the RabbitMQ mailing list, which I recommend if you have questions.  A draft interface has been proposed.  

But, why not just use the C client?  Do please get in touch and let us know.  You can email info@rabbitmq.com or post to rabbitmq-discuss.

Cheers

alexis

Answer (score 8):

For future reference, take a look at [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org) - it has a C++ client library and is very good. The problem for your use-case is that Rabbit implements AMQP 0-8 and the Qpid C++ client talks AMQP 0-10.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache QPid](http://qpid.apache.org/) seems to be relevant here. There's a C++ broker/client library [here](http://qpid.apache.org/download.html).

Note that since you're programming to a protocol (AMQP), *your broker/client don't have to be in the same language*. e.g. I'm using Scala and C# clients talking to RabbitMQ (an Erlang broker).

Comment: Thanks Brian, I got it, so I correct my question, is there a AMQP broker that has good stable C++ client library support.

Comment: I can't comment on the stability of QPid, I'm afraid. I would be more concerned about the broker stability, since that has to run independently and manage reliable queueing/delivery etc. RabbitMQ seems to work well. I suspect the thing to do is to run QPid/RabbitMQ up in your particular scenario and see how it fares.

Answer (score 1):

AMQP C++ wrapper https://github.com/akalend/amqpcpp on librabbit: https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c

Answer (score 1):

For RabbitMQ, the following library is more feature rich with good documentation:
https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, I'm kind of in the same position as the asker.

I'm looking at [IceStorm](http://www.zeroc.com/icestorm/index.html) and Apache QPid per answers above.

Currently I have rabbit MQ but it's not so easy to integrate with C++.

I think if you have control over both client and server code, and you don't need AMQP "the standard" and IceStorm does what you need, and you're cool with GPL license (or ready to buy a license from zeroC) .. IceStorm seems to be the most stable and cross-language solution out there.